# Scala Nested Function - Invocation

Tags: scala

I have created nested function in scala as below which i didn't get any error.
But when i call this function am getting below error.

Function -

```
  def f1( a: Int, b: Int, f: (Int,Int) => Int ): Int = {  

  def f2( c: Int, b: Int ): Int = {
    println("Welcome to Inner Function")
    return  c*b
  }

  a match {
    case 1 => f2(a,f(b,a))
    case 2 => f2(a,b)            
  }

}
```

Function Call -

`f1(3,4,(a,b) => a+b)`

Error

```
scala.MatchError: 3 (of class java.lang.Integer)
  at f1(<console>:31)
  ... 49 elided
```

Comment: Well, you don't have a `case` for three in your `match`. So the function does not know what to return here.

Comment: Also, do not use return in your code, please read this [topic](https://blog.knoldus.com/scala-best-practices-say-no-to-return/)

Answer (score 1):

As written in the comment, 3 does not match any pattern(case) in pattern matching.
Please see the [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/MatchError.html) that describes this error.